# C# sqlCommand.Parameters don't Select properly

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, parameters, sqlcommand

I have a code that should test a login.
When I execute literally, it works, returning one row (that's expected). When I use parameters on sqlcommand, I don't get any row.

It works (literal values for username and password):

```
string strConn = 'string connection';
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
sqlCommand.Connection = conn;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
sqlCommand.CommandText = @"select *
                           from
                              Usuario
                           where
                              Username = 'test' and
                              Password = CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), ashBytes('MD5', 'test'), 2)";

conn.Open();
SqlDataReader ret = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

But it doesn't work (parameters values for username and password):

```
string strConn = 'string connection';
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
sqlCommand.Connection = conn;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
sqlCommand.CommandText = @"select *
                           from
                              Usuario
                           where
                              Username = @login and
                              Password = CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), ashBytes('MD5', @pass), 2)";

SqlParameter user = new SqlParameter("@login", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50) { Value = "test" };
SqlParameter pass = new SqlParameter("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50) { Value = "test" };

List<SqlParameter> list = new List<SqlParameter>();
list.Add(user);
list.Add(pass);

sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(list.ToArray<SqlParameter>());

conn.Open();
SqlDataReader ret = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

I don't have an sintax error or something like that. The second code just don't returns rows.
I've tried to use sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue, but I have no success too.

Comment: Do you mean [HashBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx)? What is _ashBytes_?

Comment: @felipe-müller, have you solved your problem?

Comment: Yeah! @Igor solved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'test'` and `N'test'` are not the same thing when you convert them to a hash. One is ASCII and the other is Unicode. If they are both ASCII then use `SqlDbType.VarChar` (not `SqlDbType.NVarChar`) in your parameter.

---

Difference illustrated in Sql

```
DECLARE @passUnicode Nvarchar(100) = N'test'
DECLARE @passAscii varchar(100) = 'test'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', @passAscii), 2) AS [Md5OfAscii]
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', @passUnicode), 2) AS [Md5OfUnicode]
```

Results

```
098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6, C8059E2EC7419F590E79D7F1B774BFE6
```

---

## Side notes

### Password Hashing

I recommend against storing passwords as MD5, MD5 is simply not secure. There are plenty of alternatives out there like `pbkdf2`, `bcrypt`, and `scrypt` to name a few of the more generally accepted secure password hashing algorithms.

### c# structure

When working with Ado.net (*or with any resources for that matter*) you should wrap your Connections, DataReaders, Adapters, etc that implement `IDisposable` in `using` blocks. This will ensure external resources are always freed, even in the event of a connection.

Comment: thks!!! I didn't know this diference between varchar and nvarchar. I didn't even knew the nvarchar type. The use of md5 was just for a simple aplication, will not be the final cryptography, but thanks for advices!

Answer (score 0):

```cs
string connectionString = "";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand
    {
        CommandText = @"select * from Usuario where Username = @login and Password = CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HASHBYTES('MD5', @pass), 2)",
        CommandType = CommandType.Text,
        Connection = connection
    })
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("login", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50) { Value = "test" });
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("pass", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50) { Value = "test" });

        connection.Open();

        using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```